# Jquery not working properly for button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

Very simple code, for some reason nothing I try will work! I have obviously imported Jquery, jqueryUI, ajax, all the things I need imported (more than once!). But for some reason this button does not want to be clicked using Jquery! I got it to work with onClick, but I would like to be using jquery for this. SOS!

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#heyo").click(function(){
alert();
});

$("input").click(function(e){
var id1 = e.target.id;
alert(id1);
 });

$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
alert();
});

function pie(){
//alert();
}

</script>

<body>
loading...
<input type="button" id="heyo" onclick="pie()" value="ff" />
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap you jquery code with `$(document).ready(function() {})` to make sure all the DOM objects have been loaded before accessing them with jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

       $("#heyo").click(function(){
         alert();
       });

       $("input").click(function(e){
          var id1 = e.target.id;
          alert(id1);
        });

        $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
          alert();
          });

   });
```

Comment: AHHH OMG thank you I forgot about that! Wow I feel stupid now :)

Comment: Would Jquery .click work on buttons added dynamically from an Ajax call?

Comment: no, you need to use event delegation using the jquery `on` method